# Manejar funcion que puede o no devolver una promesa

Tags: javascript, nodejs

tengo una funcion a la que le envio algunos parametros, y en funcion de esos parametros hace una consulta en una BD o no. 

El tema es que necesito que si se hace la consulta en la base de datos la aplicacion espera a que termine la consulta para seguir con la ejecucion. Para eso utilizo promesas.

El problema es que si finalmente no se hace una consulta a la BD, el codigo de la funcion no es asincrono, y no retorna una promesa, por lo que me da un error en la linea donde llamo a la funcion del tipo:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

En el caso de que no se haga una consulta a la BD como puedo hacer para devolver algun tipo de "promesa falsa" y no me tire este error?

Comment: ¿Cómo tienes tu función de consultar a la DB? ¿Cuando no consultas la base de datos usas un `reject`?

Comment: No, me falto explicar un poco mas. La funcion recibe como parametro un objeto, y hace operaciones sobre el objeto. Dependiendo del resultado de esas operaciones, puede que haga falta llamar a la BD para pedir mas datos, o si el resultado es satisfactorio sin necesidad de llamar a la BD directamente no lo hace, y retorna el resultado de las operaciones.

Comment: si no es espera una promesa agregale un `return new Promise(resolve, reject)=> resolve("mantequilla")`

Comment: perdón creo que esta mal el paradigma con el que estas trabajando ya que la función en algunos casos es asíncrona y en otros sincronía, es mejor que una función sea solo asíncrona o sincronía, tal vez deberías separar el código que esta dentro de esa función, tal vez asignar el sincrono como un comportamiento del objeto y el asíncrono por fuera

Comment: JackNavaRow eso me funcionó! Sólo que ttuve que agregar un paréntesis que engloba todo lo que va después de Promise . Gracias

Comment: Soldat25, si también es una opción, sólo que me significa hacer más líneas de código y queda un poco menos legible en la función desde la que llamo a está función que puede o no ser asíncrona.  Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si realmente quieres retornar una promesa vaciá puedes realizar lo siguiente

```
return Promise.resolve(‘’) 
return Promise.resolve(null) 
return Promise.resolve()
```

aunque el primero retorna una cadena vacia el segundo `null` y el tercero `undefined`

tu código seria el siguiente

```
function hazalgo ( objeto={})
{
 if (objeto.algunapropiedad) {
    // algo
    return Promise.resolve();
} 

// llamado db

}

hazalgo({hola:'quetal'}).then()
```

Comment: Eso fue lo que hice como lo planteo JackNavaRow. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

¿Te sirve algo como esto?

```js
function revisarBaseDatos( objeto ) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (objeto.nombre === 'Akko') {
          // Es Akko, puede consultar la base de datos.
          resolve( "conectarBaseDatos()" );
          return;
        }
        // No es Akko, vamos a hacer operaciones y regresar un error
        let n = objeto.edad + 100;
        reject(n);
        return;
      });
  }
      let persona = { nombre: 'Akko', edad: 10000}
    revisarBaseDatos(persona).then((respuesta) => {
      // Se conectó a la base de datos.
      console.log(respuesta)
    }).catch((error) => {
      // No se conectó a la base de datos
    });
```

Tienes una función la cual retorna una promesa, un resolve maneja la conexión a la base datos y un reject maneja el error.

Mandas a llamar la función y manejas el posible error con un catch.

Comment: que finalidad tiene el return ; en realidad no hace nada!